# Checkbox label full width

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a `<Checkbox>` component wrapped in a `<FormControlLabel>`. They are placed inside a container like this:

```
<FormGroup row={true} key={option.id}>
  <FormControlLabel
    className="ContractOfferOptionsSelector__option"
    key={option.id}
    control={
      <Checkbox checked={option.selected} onChange={this.handleChange} value={String(option.id)} />
    }
    label={this.renderLabel(option)}
  />
</FormGroup>

private renderLabel(option: ISelectableOption) {
    return (
      <div className="ContractOfferOptionsSelector__option">
        <span className="ContractOfferOptionsSelector__option__title">
          <span className="ContractOfferOptionsSelector__option__title__abbreviation">{option.abbreviation}</span>
          <span className="ContractOfferOptionsSelector__option__title__description">{option.description}</span>
        </span>
        <span className="ContractOfferOptionsSelector__option__price">
          {`${formatCurrency(option.price.priceInclVat)} ${t(option.price.currency)}`}
        </span>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

The label renders as a `<span>` and 'tightly' wraps the content (so it doesn't take full width of the container). I have put multiple elements inside the label (price, title...) and want to make the label take full width, so that the elements space out across full width.

I tried `.ContractOfferOptionsSelector__option {width: 100%;}` but it doesn't work because the parent is also a `<span>`? with a dynamically generated class name...

How can I control the width of the label in material-ui?

Comment: Have you figured out a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

`<span>` has a default `inline` display property.

> Inline elements:
>   - Respect left & right margins and padding, but not top and bottom
>   - Cannot have a width and height set

Try to set `display: inline-block` to your `<span>` and add `position: relative` to the `FormGroup` container.

Comment: I need more details. Can you put a snippet with your output HTML?

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

(tested with MUI v4)

```js
import React from "react";
import { Checkbox, FormControl, FormControlLabel, FormGroup, makeStyles, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <FormControl fullWidth>
      <FormGroup>
        <FormControlLabel
          classes={{
            label: classes.fullWidth
          }}
          control={<Checkbox />}
          label={<TextField label="Full width" defaultValue="Working" variant="outlined" fullWidth />}
        />
      </FormGroup>
    </FormControl>
  );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  fullWidth: {
    width: "100%",
  },
}));
```

Full code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-v4-formcontrollabel-fullwidth-issue-tjyfq9?file=/src/App.js).

## Explanation

As you pointed out in your question, both the `label` and the `control` components become `span` elements inside `FormControlLabel`, with some [default style](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/11016) as well.

To force the `label` to cover full width, you need to:

- Toggle on the [`fullWidth`](https://v4.mui.com/api/form-control/#props) prop for the `FormControl`;
- [Override](https://v4.mui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-classes) the [label CSS class](https://v4.mui.com/api/form-control-label/#css) in `FormControlLabel` to set its `width: 100%`